# Showing $\lim_{t \rightarrow T} [X(t) + X'(t)] < \infty$ for $X''(t) + X'(t) + X(t) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose $X \in C^2 [0,T]$ solves $$X''(t) + X'(t) + X(t) = 0$$ with the initial conditions as $X(0)=1, X'(0) = 0$.

I was trying to show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow T} [X(t) + X'(t)] <  \infty$ and also how the finiteness of the above limit could assure that the solution is global?

I thought of multiplying $X'$ on both sides of the differential equation which gives us - $X'X'' + (X')^2 + XX' = 0$ and then integrating both sides from $0$  to $t$ giving us -

$\int_{0}^{t} X'X'' + \int_{0}^{t} (X')^2 dt + \int_{0}^{t} X dt = t$

I was guessing that may be a  product rule could simplify a bit but it becomes a bit complex after this.

Like $(X'X)' = X''X + (X')^2$

$(X'^2)' =  2X''X'$

Any ideas?

Comment: "and then integrating both sides from 0 to t giving us"... Well, giving us $$\int_0^t(X''X'+X'X)=-\int_0^t(X')^2\leqslant0$$ hence $$X'(t)^2+X(t)^2\leqslant X'(0)^2+X(0)^2=1$$ which implies that, for every $t$, $$|X'(t)|\leqslant1\qquad |X(t)|\leqslant1$$ which is more that what you want, right?

Comment: I was thinking how $X'(t)^2+X(t)^2\leqslant X'(0)^2+X(0)^2=1$ is thru Fundamental Theorem of Calculus??

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your comment. Did you miss that $$2(X''X'+X'X)$$ is the derivative of $$(X')^2+X^2\ ?$$

Comment: yup got it!! I was only checking $X$ right side, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a second order [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)#Second_order) differential equation, and with techniques in the link, it's pretty simple to exactly find an implicit solution in terms of integration.

Comment: Clearly the best answer!